# Can I disable shadow copy in an Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We are working on a new feature that uses third-party plugins that are stored in a directory named 'Plugins'.  One particular plugin expects certain files such as the license file to be in the same directory as the plugin assembly (DLL) based on the assembly's Location value.  However, due to shadow copy the license file is in the folder where it was originally deployed and the assembly Location value is the 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' subfolder after shadow copy.  Is there any way to disable shadow copy to work around this issue?

I suggested to the plugin provider to use CodeBase rather than Location.  They are considering it, but I have to complete this feature now so I can't wait for that code change.

My current desire is to disable shadow copy so the Location property value of the assembly is the location where all the plugin files are initially deployed to.

Answer (score 0):

Cause Azure Function doesn't support web.config, have to find other ways to implement it.

In github there is one way to solve it, and in this comment it says no shadowcopy in v2, maybe you could have a try. Add this directive in your Web Deploy pubxml for your publish profile:

```
<EnableMsDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMsDeployAppOffline>
```

Comment: I set EnableMsDeployAppOffline to True in the publish profile, but the same issue occurs so it seems that shadow copying is still occurring in my application.